# Wild card in a search string become special character

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using CI3 and i have a search page. In my search page, I have a option called LIKE. I used % value before my search string, like, %dd11, which is become something like this

**WHERE t.name LIKE '�11'**

I have added 
 in the header and i also set up my charset in database config.

here is my form input field

and here is my php code

```
if (preg_match('/(LIKE).*/', $field)) {
      $field = preg_replace('/\s(LIKE)/', '', $field);
        $field =  $field.' LIKE';
        if (preg_match("/\./", $field)) {
          $where .= $field." '".$value.";
       } else {
           $where .= "t.".$field." '".$value.";
        }
}
```

can anyone tell me why its become encoded like this. please help me

Comment: The answer probably lies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279)

Comment: Actually this seems to be both a UTF-8 and URL encoding issue... `%dd` is **Ý** (url encoded) which is becoming � as it's not supported in your charset. I'm guessing you're using `urldecode()` somewhere you shouldn't be and haven't sorted the charset in the database connector maybe.

Comment: I am using urldecode() in my login module, not in this module.  And this is how I set up char set in db file; $db['tiffinTom']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['tiffinTom']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';

Answer (score 0):

After using `Utf8` encoding in your page, open the file containing this character with notepad++ and click on `Enconding` menu, then choose `convert to utf8 without boom`. Save and run again.

You can use another text editor, notepad++ is just an example

Comment: Yes, I did..I used Notepad++ and sublime both...but no luck

Comment: sorry, I am not good at formatting text in commets section..therefore, i have added my code in my question